# How to access Maven placeholders from a Maven Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, build, placeholder

## The original problem

I'm trying to automate my deploying system to my website, but I need to know the actual name of the artifact. I'm using Github Pages, so I don't have backend script possibilities to search for the file extensions, name string contains etc.

### My planned solution

I'm about to create a Maven Plugin, and export the final artifact name during the build.

### Other encountered problem

To achieve my solution, I have to access the placeholders during the build lifecycle. However, I couldn't find any resource about doing so.

## TL;DR;

How can I access Maven build lifecycle placeholders from a Maven Plugin?

Comment: What kind of placeholders are you talking about? The version number? The final artifact name is usually `artifactId-version.extension`.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how can I access it? Any way? (script, shell, existing plugin, own plugin, less effort favoured)

Comment: in the pom, you can just read the properties like ${project.version}. In a maven plugin you can inject the maven project object.

Comment: Oh... Shame on me, I forgot about that... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to develop an own plugin to deploy a project to...wherever. You can use the [Wagon Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html):

> It allows you to upload resources from your build to a remote location using wagon.

See [Maven Wagon](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/) for the supported transports.

Within its `<configuration>` you can use `<includes>**/${project.build.finalName}*</includes>` (default: `${artifactId}-${version}`) which is an element of [the `build` element](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element). Be aware of:

> The term "finalName" is kind of a misnomer, [...]. For example, if the `maven-jar-plugin` is configured to give a jar a `classifier` of `test`, then the actual jar defined above will be built as `my-project-1.0-test.jar`.